# How to make content over several grids?

Tags: html, footer

I have a [footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv3YK.png) that is made in JS, and is styled in css with

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
```

But i would like to have the copyright part at 100%, and not only in the first grid row, is it possible to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use grid-column: 1 / -1;  This will set the item to start at 1 and the -1 aspect will tell the footer to extend all the way to the end of the grid no matter how many columns you have.

```css
/* use what ever your footer is selected as in css*/ {
 grid-column: 1 /-1;
 }
```